# Save ID to Firestore document

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to save the id of my document as a property as well, not only as a reference on the collection. At the moment I save it like this:

```
const newSet: AngularFirestoreDocument<SetModel> = this.AngularFirestore.doc('users/' + this.navParams.data.userId);

    // adding user to our ddbb
    newSet.collection('sets').add(this.set)
      .then(function (docRef) {
        // ok
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // error
      });
```

Would be that possible? Or do I need to save it, get the id and update it again?

PS this is my ddbb structure:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From quickly scanning the [reference documentation for `CollectionReference.add(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) I see that `add(...)` returns a promise. It seems there is no way to get the auto-generated ID before the document is created.

But keep in mind that the document IDs are just client-side keys that are statistically guaranteed to be unique.

This [code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/6abd6484730971e2390b2b9acbb61800852fb350/packages/firestore/src/api/database.ts#L1754) shows what the JavaScript SDK does to generate the ID, which just boils down to calling [`AutoId.newId()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/6abd6484730971e2390b2b9acbb61800852fb350/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L36). You can also call (or include in case it isn't publicly exported) this in your own code, and then use `doc(myId)` instead of `add()`.

Comment: But if I used AutoId.newId() I'm going to save a different id? Not sure if I'm following you...
I was thinking to create a new id, something like this:     const newSetID = '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
It would be different but well... I can work with that one. It's just a reference at the end

Comment: I'm not sure if you could also make this generated id the default one

Comment: Your code is similar to `AutoId.newId()`, except that the latter is much less likely to generate a duplicate ID. There is no such thing as a "default id" in Firestore: whatever you specify to `document(myNewId)` is the ID of the document. If you don't specify anything there, or call `add()` the Firestore SDK generates an ID for you with the code I linked.

Comment: I can't use a different one anyway... When I do       const newSet: AngularFirestoreDocument<SetModel> = this.AngularFirestore.doc('users/' + this.navParams.data.userId + '/' + this.navParams.data.set.id); I need to point to the "real" one. The one as a reference on the collection, not as a property of my document anyway

Comment: How can I generate this AutoId.newId()? I tried with my NewSet but it doesn't have any AutoId property/method

Comment: You can just copy the code from `AutoId.newId()` as a first try.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought I had to call the method. The only difference using this as a property and not as a collection reference (if I'm not wrong) is that I'd have to do a query first like this:       newSet.collection('sets', ref => ref.where('id', '==', myIdAsProperty')); and do a set.
I'll publish later on the changes that I made to double check with you anyway

Comment: I'm getting crazy finding some references to how to update a document using a query. So far everything I found was related to GET something

Comment: I could get the document using this query, take the ID and update the document using this ID but there's a problem here: I'm a free user. If I do X number of GETs from my ddbb I'd have to pay at some point. Using this approach I'd have to check every time I want update my ddbb

Comment: That's why I started this answer with a way for you to pre-generate an ID and then add a document with that ID (using `doc(...)` instead of `add()`). That way you only write once, instead of write-read-write.

Comment: If I pre-generate a document with an auto generate id (using Auto.newId()) and I save this id as a property this works, but when I try to find this document I need to something like this:       const newSet: AngularFirestoreDocument<SetModel> = this.AngularFirestore.doc('users/' + this.navParams.data.userId + '/sets');
 But I can't select the document inside Sets that I want. I'll add also a screenshot of my ddbb, maybe that helps

Comment: I think I created a mess asking for something that I didn't really need here. I posted a solution for my problem and accepted your answer as solution. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 11):

1 - create a const id.
2 - set id in object.
3 - save

```
  createEvent(set){
    const id = this.firestore.createId();
    set.id = id;
    return this.firestore.doc(`users/${id}`).set(ev);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, simplest answer on here.

Comment: What class "this.firestore" represets? Collection?
Can't find this on documentation

Comment: constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

Comment: Assuming I create e.g. thousands of documents in one process, will this (possibly) lead to duplicate IDs? (assuming that createId() does not "reserve" the ID for some time)

Comment: In short, auto-generate iDs are statistically unique with a good enough probability to consider it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

if this is still the a question, here is what I found, 
you need to create an empty doc and get the id and then set the document content.
in your case it would be something like this.

```
const newDoc = newSet.collection('sets').doc()
const newDocRef = await newDoc.get()
```

and now set the whole document:

```
await newSet.collection('sets').doc(newDocRef.id).set({
    docId: newDocRef.id,
    // res of the document
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here other options.

In Firebase:

```
saveAlert(alert: Alert) {
    const alertsCollection = this.firestore.collection<Alert>('alerts');
    const id = this.firestore.createId();
    alert.code = id;
    return alertsCollection.doc(id).set(alert);
}
```

In NodeJS:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        code: '',
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description
    }
    const reference = db.collection('alerts').doc();
    data.code = reference.id;
    await reference.set(data);
    res.json({ status: 'success', data: { alert: data } });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting my documents with this:

```
this.itemsCollection.valueChanges()
```

I changed it to:

```
this.sets = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges()
```

Now I can get they id with `$key` and update my document without extra references.

More info:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1278

[How to get firebase id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939580/how-to-get-firebase-id)

Edit: this is the solution I needed but not exactly for what I was looking for here

Answer (score 0):

I think the this would be a good solution if your intention is to know the record's id when querying the collection.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('sets').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        this.sets.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This show how you can set your own ID in a document, replace MY_ID to your own ID then use the SET command to store the object into the document. this function return void, so you cant check or get any callback.

```
db.collection("persons").doc("MY_ID").set({
    name: "JOHN",
})
```

this example show how to store in the person collection a obj. with name JOHN.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25732739)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i ended up doing this. I create a document and then add the data after receiving the promise.

```
firebase.firestore.collection('instances').doc("WDXmpzpY1TWRIJjeBNrx")
.collection("suppliers").add({}).then(docRef 
=> {
    firebase.firestore.collection('instances').doc("WDXmpzpY1TWRIJjeBNrx")
    .collection("suppliers").doc(docRef.id).set({
       name:this.supplierForm.name,
       phone:this.supplierForm.phone,
       email:this.supplierForm.email,
       address:this.supplierForm.address,
       gstNo:this.supplierForm.gstNo,
       uniqueID: docRef.id,
    })
 }).catch(err => {console.log(err)})
```