# Generate unique ID like Firebase Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a document in firestore with an unique id and a name after the unique id. For this, I want to create the same kind of the firebase firestore unique ids.

- How can I create an unique ID with the kind of a auto generated firestore id?
- Is there a function in the Firebase Admin SDK?

**UPDATE:**

As Frank van Puffelen mentied in the comments, the AutoId is the right choice for me!

Here is the function I use on server-side with node.js:

```
function generateUniqueFirestoreId(){
  // Alphanumeric characters
  const chars =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  let autoId = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    autoId += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
  }

  return autoId;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`AuthId.newId()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/6abd6484730971e2390b2b9acbb61800852fb350/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L36). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284184/save-id-to-firestore-document/48284468#48284468

Comment: Thats it! Please add this as answer.

Comment: A shorter yet equivalent solution:
`
const FirestoreAutoId = () => {
  const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  return Array.from({ length: 20 }).reduce((acc) => \`${acc}${chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length))}\`);
};`

Answer (score 2):

There's the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package you could use.

Comment: i know about the uuid package, but i need an id with the kind of the firestore auto generated id. thank you

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with what you mean by "firestore auto generated id"?

Comment: p8s3R6LZrE43MbJWyyKb