# I am posting some data to firestore, and i'm trying to generate a post ID which is th same as the document Id but its not giving me a correct value

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I,m sending data to firestore and i want to attach the post id as post_id for each post i send...I'm using android

```
final String randomName= FieldValue.serverTimestamp().toString();
// final String postId2=firebaseFirestore.collection("posts").document().getId();
final String postId2=firebaseFirestore.collection("posts").getParent().getId();
StorageReference filepath=storageReference.child("houses_desc").child(randomName+ ".jpg");
filepath.putFile(postImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            String downloadUri=task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
            Map<String,Object> houseMap=new HashMap<>();
            houseMap.put("user_id",current_user_id);
            houseMap.put("image1",downloadUri);
           // houseMap.put("image2",mPostImage2);
            houseMap.put("house_type",title);
            houseMap.put("desc",description);
            houseMap.put("price",price);
            houseMap.put("province",stateProvince);
            houseMap.put("city",city);
            houseMap.put("email",email);
            houseMap.put("post_id",postId2);
            houseMap.put("time_stamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this before for JavaScript. See [Save id to Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284184/save-id-to-firestore-document/48284468#48284468).

In the [Android SDK implementation of `CollectionReference.document()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/4a02ae388f7bbc3c44bdd6422243eb2597dcf905/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.java#L97), the ID of the new document is determined by calling:

```
Util.autoId()
```

If you look at the [source for `Util.autoId`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/4a02ae388f7bbc3c44bdd6422243eb2597dcf905/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/Util.java#L42) it is a simple random ID generator. You can either call Firestore's `Util.autoId()` from your code, or implement something similar yourself.

```
final String postId2 = Util.autoId();
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm getting what you're saying

Comment: Can you please try to answer in the context of the above question. Kindly

Comment: That's precisely what I did. I showed you the code of how to generate your own auto-id, and gave links of how it works. :-/